# Notepad++ plugin for Ctrl+click to method

Tags: plugins, methods, click, notepad++, ctrl

Hi all I use many text editors but mainly notepad++ and I search for functionality similar to Komodo Edit. You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button and click on a method and property and it jump to its definition.

Is there plugin for npp that do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SourceCookifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) looks to do what you want, as well as a few other features that come along with parsing the open files.

Comment: Don't works for me, get error "'ctags.exe' not found!"

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this for a long time time but not really found anything. I think this is because Notepad++ is meant to be a lightweight editor and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click would mean indexing of code which would add weight to the functionality.

I use Netbeans. Its really quick and lightweight.

Mike

Comment: NetBeans gets slow on big projects and cosumes a lot of RAM in my opinion.